# sencha touch :: why waiting seven seconds after button touch for touch detection on iPhone (edit: seems to be the CSS! how could that be?)

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

why do I have to wait seven seconds after I touched a button inside my sencha-touch/phonegap app on iOS for the touch detection to trigger my panel-slide?

thnx!

edit: it seems to be the CSS file. if I don't load it, it works well. how could that be!?

edit again: seems to be the INSET feature! this one killed the action:

```
.x-button.x-button-pressed, 
.x-button.x-button-active, 
.x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-pressed,
 .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset #AAA1A1 0 0 39em, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0 0.1em 0;
}
```

Comment: not used sencha  but in jquery.mobile there is .live("tap"   this seems to react in real time and feels like a real app when touched, also vclick  etc, have you looked through to see if there is lower handles than say click  as click is quite far down on the scope of things

Comment: can't follow you, sorry.

Comment: basically  your probably using  Click event,   click event is after, touch tap, mouseover, mousedown all that stuff hence the delay, what you need to do is go lower and look for the touch event http://www.sencha-touch.de/examples/touch-events/   see there is a tap  you should be using tap not click

Comment: ah - ok. but in sencha touch a button has its own touch event "handler". but good idea, thanx!

Comment: I found out that it has something to do with my CSS file. I dnon't understand why, but it works well when I don't load it...

Comment: cnt help there i find that with these libraries your better without the css, the css is really simple header bar is position fixed top 0 left 0 right 0 height 50px with a gradient   container is top 50px  and footer is bottom 0  rest just do in photoshop or something and you dont get all the nonsense, i have been doing this for quite a bit now and best thing i did was scrap ALL the css

Comment: I've noted similar delays on Android phonegap, but not in iOS. I just figured it was the sloooooow emulator.

Comment: Probably that CSS snippet causes a reflow or something. That means the browser tries to recalculate everything in the DOM. What I would do is let the webkit CPU profiler run and then click on the button. That way you can see where Sencha/browser spends it's time. For iOS6 you can use mobile safari's remote debugger for that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inset of 39em`.

Wow, that is really a big one. Usually on devices 1em equals 18px. So 39em is 702px. Is that what you need?

What happends is, that DOM calcs the new layout for pressed, then you move out and it recalcs the button and then - then the tap event is fired.

So - if you do a lot of calculation for the dom it takes some time. Did you try to keep inset to 1em? Otherwise it might be faster to set the background-color to a different value.

Comment: excelent idea! indead a really big value, by mistake. thnx!